# Can I trace every request using AWS X-Ray?

Tags: amazon-web-services, audit, aws-xray, distributed-tracing

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-concepts.html#xray-concepts-sampling),

> the X-Ray SDK applies a sampling algorithm to determine which requests get traced. By default, the X-Ray SDK records the first request each second, and five percent of any additional requests.

Is it possible to trace all requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to [set the sampling rate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-console-sampling.html) to 100%.

However, as noted in the [FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/xray/faqs/):

> X-Ray should not be used as an audit or compliance tool because it does not guarantee data completeness.